# Are adaptive cards available when using Dialogflow backend for Azure chatbot?

Tags: botframework, dialogflow-es, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

Does anyone have experience using Dialogflow with Azure bots? I want to use adaptive cards but currently cannot.

I'm working on a chatbot that uses an Azure bot in Teams as the frontend and uses Google Dialogflow as the language processing backend. This was possible because Dialogflow has a skype integration [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dialogflow-integrations/tree/master/skype) that can be used as the messaging endpoint for the Azurebot.

With this setup, I have been able to work fine with intents and return some basic hero cards with buttons, text, or images. However, I would like to use adaptive cards features that are available in standard Azure and Teams-based chatbots. My goal is to use the adaptive card online designer where I can copy the payload for the card as an intent response & have it show up in the chatbot.

Do I need to update the package.json or server.js in the github [repository](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dialogflow-integrations/tree/master/skype)? My current dependencies are the following:

botbuilder "^4.4.0",  dialogflow "0.6.0",  express "^4.16.4"

Any insight is appreciated

Comment: Could you please share any document references that you are following?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Could you please share any document references that you are following?